# What terminal is this?

Tags: gnome-terminal, gui

What terminal is this and from where do I get such a beautiful terminal on Ubuntu?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Just a reminder, 16.10 is out of support. You should use either 17.04 or any of the supported LTS releases.

Comment: @pomsky yes I  will update it soon..but do you know what terminal is above?

Comment: The theme looks like something from https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes. What is the source of this image?

Comment: @muru its a screenshot  from https://www.heroku.com/

Comment: Yep, probably an oh-my-zsh theme using [powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline).

Comment: Since this is answered and appears that it will be useful to many Ubuntu users--and it is not specific to 16.10 in any way--I've edited the post to generalize it. I suggest we not close this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The terminal plays only a minor role in that: the specific colour combinations are from the terminal's palette. But the rest of it is likely to be one of those zsh themes featured in [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes), using [powerline](https://github.com/powerline/powerline). Googling "oh my zsh emoji" quickly leads you to the ["wild cherry" theme](https://github.com/mashaal/wild-cherry):

> - This is a customized version of agnoster and remy.
> - In order for this theme to render correctly, you will need a Powerline-patched font.

[image]

Note that the emoji appearance of course depends on the fonts available, and emoji fonts on Ubuntu aren't that good. The screenshot is probably from a Mac.

Comment: but how do I implement it? I mean how do I change my current terminal to this terminal?

Comment: @4M01 you install zsh, then install and configure oh-my-zsh (see instructions on https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh, then follow the wild cherry instructions). Too much bother for me to list out the steps.

Comment: is it possible on windows too?

Comment: @4M01 possibly https://www.google.co.jp/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4orqn6/setting_up_powerline_for_bash_on_windows/#ampshare=https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4orqn6/setting_up_powerline_for_bash_on_windows/